# Hide gridview but show the paging/page link?

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

Hi can I  hide gridview but keep the page row visible? 
I want user to be able to flip through the pages in gridview
and my code behind will display certain data in that gridview.

but The gridview itself is not needed for the user. I just need the page to be visible

any tricks or tips. I am thinking of using CSS
but haven't found one yet

thanks for the help

[image]

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridViewMemory" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col"><a href="">header1</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="">header2</a></th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>31668-2</td><td>6</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>31668-1</td><td>6</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>30999-3</td><td>6</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>30037-7</td><td>6</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>30037-6</td><td>6</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>30037-3</td><td>6</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>30037-10</td><td>6</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>18897-2</td><td>6</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>18109-7</td><td>6</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>18109-6</td><td>6</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td colspan="2"><table>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="">1</a></td><td><a href="">2</a></td><td><a href="">3</a></td><td><a href="">4</a></td><td><a href="">5</a></td><td><a href="">6</a></td><td><a href="">7</a></td><td><a href="">8</a></td><td><span>9</span></td><td><a href="">10</a></td><td><a href="">...</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your actual purpose for this? Seems like a hackish way to accomplish whatever it is you are actually trying to do.

Comment: it is a hack... I am very new at this. Basically I have a datatable (dt) this dt has up to 7000 records. each row in this dt has a path and file name. then I have a function that loops through each row to load the file name as images on the webpage (aspx page). but loop through 7000 records then displaying them all in one page is really slow. and the end user only sit and watch the spinning IE interface. so NOw I managed to only display 10 records at a time .. and user can use the page 1 page 2 page 3 and so on to flip through the results.

Comment: Is your `GridView` tied to an `SqlDataSource`? You don't necessarily need the `GridView` to do this. It sounds like you are just fetching 10 records from your database at a time. If you just want something to work quickly though, add a class to each row of your `GridView` and then use CSS to set their `display: none`.

Comment: mmm. yes it is tied to sql . but I am not using sqldatasource. I only use da.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(SQLString, Conn)
        da.Fill(dt)

Comment: Well, if you don't want to generate the pagination controls, I guess you could just use the CSS tip that I mentioned above. Set a class on each table row, and then hide them with display: none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Here you go:

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/smF7b/1/

```
table td, table th {
    display:none;
}
table tr:last-child td {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Just hide all `td` and `th` and show your last `tr`'s `td`s in a `table-cell` display property.